# Regex last six digits

Tags: xml, regex

I've tried this equation several times. And, I'm using regex in XML to grab the last six characters of a numeric string.

For instance, string: `ExecID=238423842394283549283523`

When I say it won't work, I mean that it still returns the whole string instead of replacing it with the last six digits.

I have an XML file that uses variables, and within that file is a rule:

`formattedText="$(ExecID:R/.*(/\d{6}$)/$1/)"`

My logs aren't telling me much. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your escaping on the regex correct?

Comment: What regex implementation are you using?

Comment: Remove the `/` in front of `\d{` `/.*(\d{6}$)/$1`. [Example](http://regexr.com?35j6d)

Comment: Are you replacing the entire string (starting with `ExecID`) or just the numeric part (starting with `2384`)? If it is the former, then David Starkey has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with regex in XML but in python you can easily match it with

```
R=re.compile("(.{6})$")
match=R.findall(string)[0]
```

be aware if you use multiline (re.M) compiler consider "$" as EOL not EOF but when you disable it it should be working

Answer (score 0):

This would be an expanded way to do it in perl, with the match on one line and the replacement after. Javascript is very similar.

```
$ExecID =~ /(\d){6}$/;
if($1) {
   $ExecID = $1;
} else {
   #no match?
}
```

Could be collapsed down, but for sake of readability I'll leave it expanded.